# Mixing PHP with HTML

Tags: php, html, mixins

I'm making a form where I need to insert 2 values for X and Y to create a table with X lines an Y rows. But I'm not able to make the Table appear. The function is being called but the HTML is being ignored, for some reason, I only get a line with the content "Line 1 Line 2 Line3... Row 1, Row 2, ...."

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" >

    X= <input type="text" name="x"  /> <br />
    Y= <input type="text" name="y"  /> <br  />
    Diferença=  <select name="expressao">
                    <option value=">"> > </option>
                    <option value="<"> < </option>
                    <option value="="> = </option>
                </select>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="enviar" value="1" />

</form>
<hr />

<?php 

function tabela () {
    tabelashow ();  
}

if (!empty($_POST['enviar'])) {

    $x=$_POST['x'];
    $y=$_POST['y'];
    $expressao=$_POST['expressao'];

    echo "O valor da expressão $x $expressao $y é ";

    if ($expressao == ">") { 
        if ($x > $y) {
            echo "Verdadeiro";
            tabela ();
            }
        else {
            echo "Falso"; }
    }

    elseif ($expressao == "<") {
        if ($x < $y) {
            echo "Verdadeiro"; }
        else { 
            echo "Falso"; }
        }

    else {
        if ($x == $y) {
            echo "Verdadeiro";
        }
        else { 
            echo "Falso"; }
        }
}

?>
<hr />
<table border="1">
<?php
function tabelashow () { 
    for ($t=1; $t<=3; $t++) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($u=1; $u<=3; $u++) {
            echo("<td>Coluna $u </td>");
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
?>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Why was this migrated? O.O

Answer (score 2):

You missed a semicolon and the word `echo` or `print` on the first line

```
<?php print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

And do what jessh said too.  Seems legit.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `tabelashow ();` before it's defined, way towards the bottom.

Switching where you call the function (https://gist.github.com/jshawl/7981130#file-so-php-L20)

with where you define it (https://gist.github.com/jshawl/7981130#file-so-php-L60) Should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that the HTML code for the table is output *before* the  tag.

Here is what your PHP outputs:

```
O valor da express�o 3 > 2 � Verdadeiro<tr><td>Coluna 1 </td><td>Coluna 2 </td><td>Coluna 3 </td></tr><tr><td>Coluna 1 </td><td>Coluna 2 </td><td>Coluna 3 </td></tr><tr><td>Coluna 1 </td><td>Coluna 2 </td><td>Coluna 3 </td></tr><hr />
<table border="1">

</table>
```

One way to solve this would be to put the `<table border="1">` tag *above* the call to tabela() like this:

```
</form>
<hr />
<table border="1">
<?php 

function tabela () {
    tabelashow ();  
}

if (!empty($_POST['enviar'])) {
...
```

OR you could echo the table tag in the tabelashow() function like this:

```
function tabelashow () { 
    echo '<table border="1">';
    for ($t=1; $t<=3; $t++) { 
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($u=1; $u<=3; $u++) {
            echo("<td>Coluna $u </td>");
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

I just tried it on my own server and it works either way.

Answer (score 1):

use echo short tag to action attribute of form ..

```
<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

What an old post. Just in case it could help somebody.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" >

    X= <input type="text" name="x"  /> <br />
    Y= <input type="text" name="y"  /> <br  />
    Diferença=  <select name="expressao">
                    <option value=">"> > </option>
                    <option value="<"> < </option>
                    <option value="="> = </option>
                </select>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="enviar" value="1" />

</form>
<hr />
<?php
$tabela_poner = false;

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $x = $_POST['x'];
    $y = $_POST['y'];
    $expressao = $_POST['expressao'];

    function tabelashow(){
        global $tabela_poner;
        if($tabela_poner):
            global $x, $y;
            ?>
            <table border="1">
                <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++): ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php for($j = 1; $j <= $y; $j++): ?>
                    <td>Fila #<?php echo $i; ?> / Coluna #<?php echo $j; ?></td>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </table>
        <?php endif; // ($tabela_poner)
    }

    function tabela(){
        global $tabela_poner;
        $tabela_poner = true;
    }

    echo "O valor da expressão $x $expressao $y é ";

    // verdad o no
    switch($expressao){
        case '>':
            if($x > $y){
                echo 'Verdadeiro';
                tabela();
            }
            else
                echo 'Falso';
            break;
        case '<':
            echo $x < $y ? 'Verdadeiro' : 'Falso';
            break;
        case '=':
            echo $x === $y ? 'Verdadeiro' : 'Falso';
    }
    ?><hr /><?php
}
?>
<?php tabelashow(); ?>
```